# What in Vim determines encoding of text sent external apps through a filter?

Tags: vim, filter

For me the same file when opened in my mac terminal sends different encoding than when opened in Macvim.

My terminal Vim sends utf-8, and my mccvim sends ASCII-8BIT. Unfortunately in my case the external program can't handle the ASCII-8BIT.

How can I force macvim to send utf-8 encoded text to external programs when filtering?

Oddly this is a new problem, and only showed up after my system crashed 2 days ago. Very confused.

Comment: That is why vimrc files are used. You can force files to be encoded in specific encodings. Try `:set encoding=utf8` or `set fileencoding=utf8` in ~/.vimrc file. This might work.

Comment: I had already checked these two, and they didn't seem to alter the behavior.   But there may be combinations I haven't tried.